# get splash image in landscape mode for iPad App

Tags: ios

I am unable to get the landscape splash image while launching the app in iPad. App is supported only for iPad. I tried using the 1024x768 image, but still not working.Even I have tried adding UIInterfaceOrientation key to info.plist

Answer (score 0):

All file names are case-sensitive.

rename them to : Default-Landscape.png & Default-Landscape@2x.png

with capital "D"

in simulator it isnt case-sensitive but in device it is

**iPad-only applications:**

Create a launch image for each supported orientation in the PNG format. Each launch image must be 1024 x 748 pixels (for landscape) or 768 x 1004 pixels (for portrait).

Default launch image files:

```
Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png - upside-down portrait version.

Default-LandscapeLeft.png - left-oriented landscape version.

Default-LandscapeRight.png - right-oriented landscape version.

Default-Portrait.png - generic portrait version.

Default-Landscape.png - generic landscape version.

Default.png - default portrait launch. Its usage is strongly discouraged, use more specific launch images instead.For iPad launch images, do not include the status bar region.
```

Create launch images of these sizes:

```
For portrait:

768 x 1004 pixels

1536 x 2008 pixels (high resolution)
```

For landscape:

```
1024 x 748 pixels

2048 x 1496 pixels (high resolution)
```

Answer (score 0):

please following code in APPDelegate methods.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        if(IS_IPAD)
        {
         NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
        }
    }
```

It may be helpful.